# PDO MySQL prepared statement with optional where statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am working on a query that is submitted from a form with a variety of search options that could or could not be included in my query. Is there a better way to do this dynamically as this doesn't seem to work?

I keep getting error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean`. I know there is a lot going on here and I didn't want to put a ton of code to read through. So to make a long story short, when I echo out $sql my select statement looks good, but no matter what I do I keep getting the same error which tells me there is something wrong with the statement. Is this approach even workable or do I need to use another method? If so what is a better approach?

```
 $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT mt.id, mt.name, mt.phone 
       FROM main_table mt
       LEFT JOIN jnct_tbl_srvstate st ON mt.id = st.mt_id
       LEFT JOIN jnct_tbl_equip eq on mt.id = eq.mt_id
       LEFT JOIN jnct_tbl_accessory ac ON mt.id = ac.mt_id
       LEFT JOIN tbl_car c ON mt.id = c.mt_id
       WHERE mt.id = c.id";

      if($state_array_count != 0){
         $sql.= " AND srvstate_id IN ($st_holders)";
      }    
      if($equip_array_count != 0){
         $sql.= " AND equip_id IN ($eq_holders)";  
      }
      if($accessory_array_count != 0){
         $sql.= " AND accessory_id IN ($ac_holders)";


      $sql.= " ORDER BY mt.id";

      $query = $db->prepare($sql);
```

Incorporating the if statements above is what I really need help with.

```
 if($state_array_count != 0){     
     foreach($state_array as $st_placeholder => $st_value) {
        if($st_value != '') {
            $st_placeholder = ":$st_placeholder";
            $query->bindValue($st_placeholder, $st_value);
        }
     }
 }

 if($equip_array_count != 0){
      if($eq_value != '') {
          foreach($equip_array as $eq_placeholder => $eq_value) {
            $eq_placeholder = ":$eq_placeholder";
            $query->bindValue($eq_placeholder, $eq_value);
       }
    }
 }

 if($accessory_array_count != 0){
    foreach($accessory_array as $ac_placeholder => $ac_value) {
        if($ac_value != '') {
            $ac_placeholder = ":$ac_placeholder";
            $query->bindValue($ac_placeholder, $ac_value);
        }
    }
 }
```

```
 $results = $query->execute(); 

 $rs = $results->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `execute()` method does not return a results object. It returns a boolean, true or false.

`fetchAll()` is a method of the PDOStatement object. Here's an example:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();    
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks Bill!  That fixed it in about 30 seconds .  I had all the complex stuff correct, but really managed to fumble the PDO up somehow haha.